# Scala: slice() does not perform as expected

Tags: scala, output, slice

I am writing a small piece of code that will traverse a 1000 digit number, taking 13 digits at each step. For e.g. in the first iteration it should take digits at places 0-13, in the next iteration it should take digits at place 1-14 and so on. Here is my code but my slice keeps getting smaller as i traverse over the large number. I want to slice 13 digits from the original string each time. What am i doing wrong?

```
val largeNumber = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
var current13Digits = ""

for (iterator <- 0 to (largeNumber.length-13))
  {
            println("CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS " + iterator)
            current13Digits = largeNumber.slice(iterator,13)
            println("CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE " + current13Digits)
  }
```

Output is as follows and it drops digits after every slice. What am i doing wrong?

```
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 0
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 7316717653133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 1
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 316717653133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 2
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 16717653133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 3
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 6717653133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 4
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 717653133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 5
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 17653133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 6
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 7653133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 7
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 653133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 8
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 53133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 9
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 3133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 10
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 133
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 11
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 33
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 12
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 3
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 13
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 14
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE 
CURRENT VALUE OF ITERATOR IS 15
CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE .....
```

Comment: You misunderstand the slice arguments. The second is the absolute end index, not the slice length. Have a look at the Scaladoc.

Comment: Looks like you wish to use `.sliding(13)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks, sliding works perfectly.

```
val current13Digits = largeNumber.sliding(13)
while(current13Digits.hasNext)
  {
    current13DigitsAsString = current13Digits.next()
    println("CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE " + current13DigitsAsString
    ...
  }
```

Comment: `largeNumber.sliding(13).foreach(s => println("CURRENT 13 DIGITS ARE " + s))`